# Why are boostrap classes not resolving correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my file, there are references to bootstrap styles.

All class references are defaulting to the primary color. To illustrate. this [test site](http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com), has a `button` on the top left with class `btn btn-success`, which should be green.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" data-ng-app="wtApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Writer's Tryst, where authors and publishers, producers, agents meet.</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A better way for writers to find publishers, producers and agents" />
        <link  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="frainversegment" content="!" />
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="yVui_k1sbN4TDHx-yDmol0MzU1QXaTTGlhNa_gVLzUs" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" data-integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" data-crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" data-integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" data-crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shares.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/writers-tryst.png" />
<!--
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
              document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            try {
                var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-15499108-1");
                    pageTracker._trackPageview();
                } catch (err) { }
        </script>

        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
              google_ad_client: "ca-pub-3982825388677642",
              enable_page_level_ads: true
            });
        </script>
-->
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="mainController">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Writers-Tryst">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/writers-tryst-logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Writers-Tryst">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a id="homepage" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#writers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"> Writers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#enablers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Enablers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#about" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> About</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#privacy" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> Privacy/Rules</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> Contact</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#log-in"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Log-In</a></li> 
                            <li><a id="create-account-link" href="#accounts"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Create Account</a></li> 
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" id="drop-toggle-1" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-aria-haspopup="true" data-aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a id="update-profile" href="#update-profile">Update profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="manage-uploads" href="#manage-uploads">Manage uploads</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li ><a id="reset-pwd-link" href="#reset-pwd"></a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
<!--
            <div class="google-ad-top">
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                        style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
                        data-ad-client="ca-pub-3982825388677642"
                        data-ad-slot="1133448516"></ins>
                <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            </div>
-->
        </header>
        <div id="shares">
            <!-- Twitter -->
            <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com&text=<TEXT>&via=<VIA>" target="_blank" title="twitter" class="share-btn twitter">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Google Plus -->
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com" target="_blank" title="google+" class="share-btn google-plus">
                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Facebook -->
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://writers.tryst.com" target="_blank" title="facebook" class="share-btn facebook">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- StumbleUpon (url, title) -->
            <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn stumbleupon">
                <i class="fa fa-stumbleupon"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Reddit (url, title) -->
            <a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn reddit">
                <i class="fa fa-reddit"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- LinkedIn -->
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>&summary=<SUMMARY>&source=<SOURCE_URL>" target="_blank" title="linked-in" class="share-btn linkedin">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
            </a>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Hello World</button>
        <div>
            <div id="message" class="alert m-t-10"></div>
            <div id="main" class="content">
                <!-- angular templating -->
                <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="panel panel-default">
            <div>&#169; 2016 Ronald Tornambe, Inc.</div>
        </footer>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pages.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#drop-toggle-1").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $("#update-profile").on("click", function () {
                sessionStorage.setItem("create-or-update", "update");
                console.log("session-storage=" + sessionStorage.getItem("create-or-update"))
                $("#create-account-link").trigger("click");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are overriding it in main.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons from [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) have class `.btn` plus a second class, in this case `.btn-success` and you are in your `main.css` (line 123) overriding  the class `.btn` with `background-color: blue;`

```
.btn {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

My advice to is only change the second class, that is attached to some kind of event/action of button. instead of general `.btn` (button)

Comment: I forgot I did that. Thanks. I'll mark your answer as accepted since you are on the top of the list.

Comment: @user153673 so every user that see similar answers to his/her answer with minutes apart should downvote them?

Comment: @dippas oh sorry, I haven't seen the posting time, but I cannot remove my downvote unless you edit the answer

Comment: @user153673 you can undo if you want to now.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons with `.btn` are green by default in bootstrap, but you have overridden that in `main.css` on line 123.

You can either change the class of buttons you wish to be blue, or use a different CSS selector for them.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" data-integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" data-crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" data-integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" data-crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shares.css" />
```

You created `.btn` class in css/main.css and this class overriding class in `bootstrap.css` file

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** If you are using Bootstrap as the base stylesheet, this is not an intended solution to the question! This can, however, highlight potential problem areas with overriding styles in custom stylesheets.

---

The styles for `.btn` are overridden in `main.css`. **This is caused by loading `main.css` after `bootstrap.css`.**

From Chrome DevTools:

[image: View of CSS from page]

From this image, you can see that the styles for `.btn` in `main.css` are given higher priority than those for `.btn-success` from `buttons.less` (part of Bootstrap's styles).

You can easily change the priority by moving the stylesheet for `main.css` above the one for `bootstrap.css`, which will make Bootstrap's styles higher priority than the customized ones.

Here's what your site looks as is:
[image: Main overriding Bootstrap]

And after moving `main.css`:
[image: Bootstrap overriding main]

Comment: We shouldn't move the bootstrap.css, after the custom,css. Because bootstrap.css is working as a base.css :)

Comment: True! I didn't intend for this to be a full solution, but rather a debugging tool to see where styles may be overridden and what should be fixed. Added clarification to answer.